# Why do the trash folder of Nexus never empties?

Tags: linux, maven, nexus

For my maven enterprise repository, I use Sonatype Nexus, deployed as a Tomcat6 webapp.

I've configured default snapshots cleanup task. Unfortunatly, each week (or each pair of week, don't know exactly), that machine reaches 100% disk occupation, and I have to go in the `/usr/share/tocmat6/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/snapshots/.nexus/trash` folder to perform a `rm -rf`.

This is incredibly stupid ! And I'm quite sure it's my own stupid. So, what can I do to have the trash empty task really clean up that folder ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out default configuration of "Empty trash" is to delete items older than `180` days ! This is clearly not suitable for a continuous integration server ! I changed that value to `5` days.

Comment: In a more normal mode you do not end up with that much data in the trash. How are you accumulating so much to require these regular deletes? Also if you are deleting snapshot there purge snapshots scheduled task can force delete items rather than moving them to the trash so that is something else you might want to look at.

Comment: @ManfredMoser well, our snapshots are big (like 2G bigs) and they are redeployed hourly.

Comment: Then I would configure a scheduled task purge them more regularly and  enable the direct deletion of them rather than moving them to the trash (delete immediately) ... see http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-tasks.html

Answer (score 15):

You need to configure a task to clean the trash

- Go to nexus
- log in as an administrator
- Go to Adminitration -> Scheduled tasks
- Add a task of type `Empty trash`

These instructions should work on nexus 1.8 and above. They might work on previous versions, but I don't have any installed.

Comment: This option does not exist on Nexus 3.x