# No Empty Trash scheduled task in Sonatype Nexus OSS 3

Tags: nexus

Nexus used to have a [scheduled task](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/09/nexus-scheduled-tasks/) option to [empty trash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976774/why-do-the-trash-folder-of-nexus-never-empties), but this is not present in Nexus 3:

[image: Nexus 3.5 doesn't have Empty Trash Task]

Whenever I delete Assets or Components, my blob store's size doesn't decrease, making it very difficult to maintain in the long term.

How do I empty the trash and permanently remove deleted assets and components so that the blob size goes down? Groovy scripts are welcome too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Empty Trash" seems to not exist because it is replaced by the "Compact blob store" scheduled task.

To reduce space you need to first delete the assets and components and then run the "Compact blob store" task.

Answer (score 0):

Empty Trash and Compact Blobstore are two different features that end up with similar end states. One would be the ability to see what you have deleted, and then assumedly restore something, or choose to finally delete it, which is an open box, compared to Compact Blobstore which is a black box, and just allows you to free up space.

There has been quite a bit of internal debate over this and what should be the path forward. I encourage you to file an issue about this:

https://issues.sonatype.org/projects/NEXUS/

Assumedly work can be done to make the Compact Blobstore a bit more transparent, and accomplish similar functionality as to having a "Trash can", if such is desired.